# Oracle sql Sub query to check table exists from first day to last

Tags: sql, oracle

> My requirement is to check from the
>   first date of current month ie
>   01/12/2010 with table name in the
>   format suresh_20101201 exists in the
>   database, if not then it should check
>   for table suresh_20101202 and thereon
>   till suresh_20101231 . is it possible
>   to do in oracle sql query.

for example

```
select  object_name from all_objects where object_type ='TABLE' 
and upper(object_name) = 'SURESH_' || to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'),'YYYYMMDD')  
and ROWNUM =1
```

the above query should run till last day ,if no table exists from 01 to 29th of dec.

Comment: I find it very hard to imagine how this table naming scheme would fit in a normalized database.

Comment: @symcbean: I agree, there are probably bigger problems with the database. I just hope that these tables are for some personal use, considering their names are prefixed with his name.

Comment: I stumped upon this and found your select example very helpful for a table check script I'm writing.  Works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a convenience view such as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ALL_SURESH_TABLES AS
SELECT
  table_name,
  to_date(regexp_replace(table_name, 'SURESH_([[:digit:]]+)', '\1'), 'YYYYMMDD')
    AS table_date
FROM
  ALL_TABLES
WHERE
  regexp_like(table_name, 'SURESH_[[:digit:]]+')
```

And then query it like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(table_name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY table_date)
FROM
  ALL_SURESH_TABLES
WHERE
  TRUNC(table_date, 'mm') = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm')
```

(I didn't verify the second query, but it should be straight forward once the `ALL_SURESH_TABLES` view is created)

**Edit**: In light of your comment regarding the "ORA-01830" error, I am led to believe that you have at least one table whose name starts with `SURESH_`, ends with digits, but those digits don't form a valid date. For example, this causes the same error to occur:

```
/* Notice the "date" has nine digits instead of eight */
SELECT to_date('201012088', 'YYYYMMDD') FROM DUAL
```

Therefore, I recommend you change this:

```
regexp_replace(table_name, 'SURESH_([[:digit:]]+)', '\1')
```

into this:

```
regexp_replace(table_name, 'SURESH_([[:digit:]]{8}).*', '\1')
```

The modified regular expression will only pay attention to the first eight digits after "`SURESH_`".

Comment: ur second query has error ORA-01830 date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @Suresh: Yes, but does the first query work? It should be easy once that's working.

Comment: @Adam yes first one work. but when i do simple select on the view it gives the invalid number format model.

Comment: @Suresh: have you got other table names which have numbers that aren't dates, or in a different format? e.g. `SURESH_101231`?

Comment: @Adam yes there are other tables.

Comment: @Suresh: Are you saying that there are tables whose name starts with `SURESH_` and ends with digits, but those digits are not actually a valid date? For example, are there tables named something like `SURESH_1`?